# Regarding Gaussian integers and primitive roots.

Tags: complex-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Can modular arithmetic be set up using gaussian integers instead of (non-complex) integers? If so is there an analogue of 'primitive roots' with Gaussian integers?

Comment: I noticed (1+i)^16 is conguent to 1 mod (1+4i)  (I think). This can be written as (1+i)^((1^2)+(4^2)-1) is congruent to 1 mod (1+4i). Maybe (a+bi)^(p^2+q^2-1) is congruent to 1 mod (p+qi) given p+qi is a gaussian prime. So one way to use gaussian integers in modular arithmetic is if any exponent are limited to non-complex integers..

Answer (score 1):

For primes $p=1 \pmod 4$ the number $i$ reduces either of two integers, and thus any $a+bi$ reduces to some number $\mod p$.  Primitive roots work as normal.

For primes $p=3 \pmod 4$, there is no primitive root, and one can not reduce past a modulo class $a+bi \pmod p$.

The same is true for eisenstein integers, except the modulo classes are $p=1 \pmod 6$ and $p=5 \pmod 6$.

These integer systems are closely related to the Pell systems (of the form $(\sqrt{n+2}+\sqrt{n-2})/2$), being the solutions for n=0, n=1 respectively.

For the values n=3 and greater, one can find primitive roots for both the `lower` and `upper` primes.  These have a period of $p-1$ and $p+1$ respectively.

Comment: (3+2i)=(4+3i) mod(1+i) as a trivial example of gaussian integers used in modular arithmetic. Can (11+11i) have a complete residue system ?

Comment: ${\bf Z}[i]/3{\bf Z}[i]$ is a field of 9 elements, isn't it? So the multiplicative group will be cyclic, and will have a generator, which I think one could call a primitive root.

Comment: @GerryMyerson While the group is a field of 9 elements, this does not preclude all elements being of cyclic order 3, and hence no primitive root.  A similar thing happens with numbers modulo 63, which have 36 coprimes, but the maximum cycle is 6.  Powers of the primitive root must pass through all coprimes.

Comment: @user128932 You can certianly define a modulo system based on any complex number like 11+11i.  In some cases, one can select even the nearest one.  One distribution that works is to hive off the element of $z$ (here 11), and make the remainding factor a product of distinct gaussian primes $1+i$.  The effect is to associate with each multiple of 11+11i, a rectangle of size 11*22 gaussian numbers, where the multiple forms in the corner closest to $-\infty-i\infty$.

Comment: There is (up to isomorphism) only one field of 9 elements, and the nonzero elements of a finite field always form a cyclic group. Also, the group of units has order 8, hence, no elements of order 3 at all.

Comment: @GerryMyerson  There are actually two.  One is formed by $A^3=B^3=1$, $AB=BA$, which makes eight members of order three, the other group is formed by $A^9=1$, which does have six primitive roots, and only two of order three.  These are not isomorphic.

Comment: There are 2 **groups** of 9 elements, but only one **field** of 9 elements, and the nonzero elements of that field form a cyclic group of order 8 under multiplication. When one talks about a primitive root (in this context), one is talking about a generator for the multiplicative group.

Comment: What happens when you put in something like $\pmod{2+i}$, you get a thing like $A^5=1$.  But if you have two primes, like $\pmod{(2+i)(2-i)}$, the modulus happens like $A^5=B^5=1, AB=BA$.  This also happens with primes modulo 3.  So the remainders of gaussian numbers modulo 3, are of the type $A^3=B^3=1, AB=BA$, which has elements as described.  If you want to call them groups or fields or whatnots, that does not change the way these things work.  @GerryMyerson

Comment: The nonzero remainders modulo 3 are $\{1,2,i,2i,1+i,1+2i,2+i,2+2i\}$. Let's look at the powers of $i$: $1$, $i$, $i^2=-1=2$, $i^3=2i$, $i^4=1$. See? $i$ has order 4, not 3. You will find that $1+i$ has order 8.

Comment: Ok, i forgot about that.  Thanks @GerryMyerson

Comment: @wendy.krieger if $norm$ of complex number is primitive root then complex number is primitive root of number, so if |(a+bi)| is primitive root then |(b+ai)| is also primitive root.

Comment: Not always.  It does not work in pentagonal numbers, for example.

Comment: @wendy.krieger can you please provide me link, document so i can learn about primitive root over Gaussian integer. actually i am not able to identify generate over Gaussian prime.

Comment: I only know about them first hand.

Comment: @wendy.krieger can you explain me "For primes $p=1(mod4)$ the number i reduces either of two integers, and thus any a+bi reduces to some number modp. Primitive roots work as normal"

Comment: Primes like 5 are composite by gaussian integers, dividing into 2+i, 2-i.  Or 13 = 3+2 3-2i  .  Each number is congurant to one of the numbers 0..4 or 0..12 relative to these primes.  Every prime $p=1 \pmod 4$ breaks down to two gaussian primes.

Comment: what does the last sentence means "primitive root work as norm"

Comment: It means that where 2 is a primitive root of 5 or 13, then 2 is a primitive root of 2+i or 3+2i.

Comment: @wendy.krieger thanks